# How to set the icon when QTabBar is set to east or west?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to rotate the content of tab in a verticle QTabBar. So I tried to inherit QProxyStyle, and override the drawItemText func, it works well.But when I tried to rotate the icon to show the pixmap by override the drawItemPixmap func

```
void myTabStyle::drawItemPixmap(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect, int alignment,const QPixmap &pixmap) const
{
    painter->save();
    painter->rotate(90);
    QRect r = QRect(0,0,rect.width(),rect.height());
    QProxyStyle::drawItemPixmap(painter,r,Qt::AlignRight,pixmap);
    painter->restore();
}
```

no matter how I translate the painter,or set clip rect by `ClipRect(r,Qt::NoClip)` ,the pix map just show in the middle of tab,if I translate the painter to left side,there will be just a part of pixmap in the middle.I guess the qt clip pixmap. How to solve this problem.